# SQL AVG value of one column where another column equal specific value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm given data of pitchers, the pitch type, and the pitch speed.

```
|------------------------------------------------|
| day | inning | pitcher| pitch_type| pitch_speed|
|  1       1        AE1     fastball|      97    |
|  1       1        AE1     fastball|      94    |
|  1       1        AE1      slider |      83    |
|  1       2        AE1     fastball|      96    |
|  1       2        AE1      slider |      86    |
|  1       2        AE1     fastball|      97    |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

Is there a way of querying the data to get the avg value of the pitch speed for a specific pitch type.

I.E. a way to return fastball_speed = 96 and slider_speed = 84.5 (the average)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
select pitch_type, avg(pitch_speed) from your_table group by pitch_type
```

BTW please when specifying sample data, use CTE to make work easier for solvers:

```
#standardSql
with t as (
select   1 as day,      1 as inning,       'AE1' as pitcher,     'fastball' as pitch_type,    97 as pitch_speed union all
select   1 as day,      1 as inning,       'AE1' as pitcher,     'fastball' as pitch_type,    94 as pitch_speed union all
select   1 as day,      1 as inning,       'AE1' as pitcher,     'slider'   as pitch_type,    83 as pitch_speed union all
select   1 as day,      2 as inning,       'AE1' as pitcher,     'fastball' as pitch_type,    96 as pitch_speed union all
select   1 as day,      2 as inning,       'AE1' as pitcher,     'slider'   as pitch_type,    86 as pitch_speed union all
select   1 as day,      2 as inning,       'AE1' as pitcher,     'fastball' as pitch_type,    97 as pitch_speed
)
select pitch_type, avg(pitch_speed) from t group by pitch_type
```

Comment: Is there a way to put it as a CASE statement?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do in case statement. Your request is the simplest possible usage of group by + aggregation. If you want something other than two rows times two columns with values (fastball, slider, 96, 84.5), please describe it more precisely.